# htaccess redirect domain.com/index.php?page=home to domain.com/home

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

What is the code for a simple redirect rule in htaccess that make this change :

`domain.com/index.php?page=home` => `domain.com/home`

From `page=home`, `home` is a dynamically generated page slug.

Also when on `domain.com/somepage`, output of `echo $_GET['page']` should be "somepage"

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

The RewriteConds makes sure that you aren't trying to access a real page (if you do so, the url will not be rewritten)
The RewriteRule mets every url like `http://domain.com/somepage` with or without an ending slash (but not `domain.com/somefolder/somepage`)
In this example the url displayed to the user doesn't change, if you want so you have to add `[R=301]` behind the RewriteRule.